# Download html table data into EXCEL files not working properly

Tags: html, jquery

Excel downloading function. My HTML Table contain 5 page pagination and I want to export to Excel all HTML Table I am calculating total `tr` length but i am only able to download only 1st page of table how can i download all record in HTML Table. (My table contain 5 page one page contain 9 records)

**Paging**

```
function Paggination() {
            $('#test').after('<div id="nav"></div>');
            var rowsShown = 10;
            var rowsTotal = $('#test tbody tr').length;
            var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
            for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
                var pageNum = i + 1;
                $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
            }
            $('#test tbody tr').hide();
            $('#test tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
            $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
            $('#nav a').bind('click', function () {

                $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
                var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
                var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
                $('#test tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
                    css('display', 'table-row').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
            });
        }
```

I am facing problem : table value is repeat ting

[image]

**My Function**

```js
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var textRange; var j = 0;
    tab = document.getElementById('test'); // id of table
    tabbtest = $('#test tr').length;

    for (j = 0; j < tabbtest; j++) {
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.innerHTML + "</tr>";
        //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))// If Internet Explorer
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus();
        sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to test.xls");
    }
    else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

    return (sa);
}
```

**Table**

```
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display: none"></iframe>
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();">EXPORT </button>


<table id="test" class="width100p borderTable table_new"></table>
```

**DOM**

```html
<table id="test" class="width100p borderTable table_new">
    <table id="lineItemTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tr-Highlighted" style="height: 30px; display: table-row;">
                <td class="align-text-center">Sr.No</td>
                <td class="align-text-center" style="font-weight:bold !important">User Login</td>
                <td id="tdUserName" class="align-text-center" style="font-weight:bold !important">User Name</td>
                <td class="align-text-center" style="font-weight:bold !important">Status</td>
                <td class="align-text-center" style="font-weight:bold !important">Action</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">1</td>
                <td class="width10p">1212</td>
                <td class="width24p">nitish</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                <td class="width4p"><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog"
                        data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20"
                            width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img
                            src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">2</td>
                <td class="width10p">1234</td>
                <td class="width24p">NKP</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                <td class="width4p"><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog"
                        data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20"
                            width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img
                            src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">3</td>
                <td class="width10p">82278</td>
                <td class="width24p">Melquiades Sadda</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                <td class="width4p"><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog"
                        data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20"
                            width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img
                            src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">4</td>
                <td class="width10p">86049</td>
                <td class="width24p">Ranjith Nair</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                <td class="width4p"><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog"
                        data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20"
                            width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img
                            src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">5</td>
                <td class="width10p">86287</td>
                <td class="width24p">Habiburrehman Mukhtar Shaikh</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                <td class="width4p"><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog"
                        data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20"
                            width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img
                            src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">6</td>
                <td class="width10p">920041</td>
                <td class="width24p">Nitish Kumar Patel</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                <td class="width4p"><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog"
                        data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20"
                            width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img
                            src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">7</td>
                <td class="width10p">92004190</td>
                <td class="width24p">123</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                <td class="width4p"><a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog"
                        data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20"
                            width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img
                            src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: table-row;">
                <td class="width4p align-text-center">8</td>
                <td class="width10p">96926</td>
                <td class="width24p">Benjamin</td>
                <td class="width14p">Active</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</table>
```

Second Page Record

```
<tr style="display: table-row; opacity: 1;">
 <td class="width4p align-text-center">10</td>
 <td class="width10p">Apple</td><td class="width24p">qqq</td>
 <td class="width14p">Active</td><td class="width4p">
 <a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-book- 
 id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20" width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record">
<img src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a>
</td></tr>
<tr style="display: table-row; opacity: 1;">
<td class="width4p align-text-center">11</td>
<td class="width10p">BDC banga</td>
<td class="width24p">BDC Banga</td>
<td class="width14p">Active</td>
<td class="width4p">
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" class="open-AddBookDialog" data-book-id="my_id_value"><img src="Images/edit.png" height="20" width="20"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#my_modal" class="delete-Record"><img src="Images/delete.png" height="18" width="18"></a></td></tr>
```

Since i am getting  `HTMLCollection()` as 0 so might be i am not able to download this excel in proper manner

[image]

Comment: Please include the HTML code of your table.

Comment: @Riccardo You mean DOM Explorer Table Code Ryt?

Comment: You have included only one page of data in your post. What about the other pages? How are they loaded?

Comment: Wait i updating once again all data Kindly check my updated code

Comment: @Riccardo can we please explain me where i am doing mistake

Comment: How is paging done? Are you loading the whole table in your DOM and just showing the current page, or are the pages loaded through ajax?

Comment: BTW, you are getting 0 rows from your `tab` object because the table which has some rows is the one with ID `lineItemTable`, while `tab` points to the table `test`.

Comment: @Riccardo you mean instead of binding `test` i have to bind `lineItemTable` ? can you please post answer for that ? kindly check i have updated my question how i am performing paging